# Finding a function ,satisfying the given properties

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, examples-counterexamples

Finding a function of two variables , satisfying $$\lim_{\left(x,y \right)\rightarrow \left({x}_{0},{y}_{0} \right)}f\left(x,y \right)=+\infty ;$$ and

for $\forall\delta>0, \exists y^{'},y^{''}\in (y_{0}-\delta,y_{0}+\delta)\setminus\lbrace y_{0}\rbrace,s.t.  \lim_{x\rightarrow {x}_{0}}f\left(x,{y}^{'} \right)=+\infty,\lim_{x\rightarrow {x}_{0}}f\left(x,{y}^{''} \right)\in\mathbb{R}.$

---

I find a two variables function: $\lim_{\left(x,y \right)\rightarrow \left(0,0 \right)}\frac{1+x^{2}+y^{2}}{x^{2}}=+\infty,$ 
but  $\forall\delta>0,$ all $y^{'} \in (-\delta,\delta)\setminus\lbrace 0 \rbrace, \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f\left(x,{y}^{'} \right)=+\infty.$

---

Any of your help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Consider $x_0,y_0=0$ and
\begin{align*}
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}, & y>0 \\ \frac{1}{x^2}, & y\leq 0\neq x \\ \frac{1}{y^2}, & y<0=x \\
0, & y=0=x\end{cases}.
\end{align*}
Then $f(x,y)\geq\min\{\frac{1}{x^2},\frac{1}{y^2}\}$ for each $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$ and hence $f(x,y)\to\infty$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$. Moreover, for $y<0\neq x$, $f(x,y)=1/x^2\to\infty$ as $x\to0$, and for $y>0$, $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\to\frac{1}{y^2}\in\mathbb R$ as $x\to0$.

Comment: Seemingly,your example is gonna be okay.but  thinking carefully,your example function defined in $\mathbb{R^{2}} \setminus \lbrace y< 0  \wedge  x=0\rbrace$.then $\forall \delta>0,y\in (-\delta,0)$ have no defintion,so you said for $y<0 \ne x,f(x,y)=1/x^{2}\to +\infty$ as $x\to 0$ is not correct! 
   Thanks all the same!

Comment: To say that $f(x,y)\to\infty$ as $x\to0$ does not require $f$ to be defined at $x=0$. But you are right about the rest; I corrected my answer.

Comment: That's right, you said 
"to say that $f(x,y) \to +\infty $ as $x\to 0$ does not require $f$ to be defined at $x=0$."

But from your second edited function, we have for $y<0 \ne x,f(x,y)=1/y^{2}\to 1/y^{2}(\in\mathbb{R})$  not $\to +\infty$ as $x\to 0$ .So your second edition also can not satisfied the condition that my question given.

Comment: No. If $y<0$ and $x\neq0$, we are in the second case of my definition, and there we have $f(x,y)=1/x^2\to0$ as $x\to0$.

Comment: Oh! I made a mistake in my second comments.That's a nice example your second edtion given. +1